# Как удалить папку с длинным названием (путем)?

Tags: файлы, windows-10, файловая-система

У меня одна программа создала папку в папке... с одинаковым названием. При удалении Windows не может такое длинное название удалить. Пробовал сжать в архив, но архив выдаёт ошибку. Как можно удалить папку в папке

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44081985/13970074